# What typing should be used for connected action creators?

Tags: reactjs, redux, flowtype

I use Flow in my React+Redux project. I have a component which is connected to store and use several action creators. I want to set a type for this action creator in `type Props`.

Previously I used just `Function` type for such situation. So it looked like:

```js
type Props = {
  onSomeEvent: Function,
}
```

Now I want to replace just `Function` with something more specific like `() => void`. However, I'm not sure what exactly will return the connected function.

Should it be just `() => void` if this function doesn't return anything or since it is action creator it should be `() => Action`?

P.S. I've already checked Flow docs about it here:
https://flow.org/en/docs/react/redux/

However, it says only about regular Action Creators, not connected to the component as a prop.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the following approach:

```
// actions.js

type OnSomeEventType = () => SomeAction;
export const onSomeEvent: OnSomeEventType = () => {
  // some implementation here
};

// Component.jsx

import type { OnSomeEventType } from 'actions.js';

type Props = {|
  onSomeEvent: OnSomeEventType,
|};
```

So you can explicitly specify that your component depends on some function interface.

If you don't want to specify such a dependency (and that can be ok in your case), you can use something like this:

```
type Props = {|
  onSomeEvent: () => mixed,
|}
```

Because usually you don't care inside a component what the action creator returns: you just fire it and forget.